# Getting javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"Students")

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jersey

I am trying to get a webservice that will generate an XML response via Jersey, with the data in a hashmap.

I am receiving the following error message:

> Caused by: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException:javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"students"). Expected elements are 
>   <{}student>,<{}student-list>

I ran into some serious issues with attempting to generate the XML response from the hashmap, so I am trying to turn the hashmap into an array list and use that for the XML response

```
@GET
@Path("/student")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,"text/xml"})//changed from text/xml
public Response readStudents(){
    final List<Student>sl = studentList.getStudentListAll();

    final GenericEntity<List<Student>>entity = new GenericEntity<List<Student>>(sl){};

    return Response.ok(entity).build();
}
```

The student class:

```
@XmlRootElement //(name = "student")
public class Student {
private String name;
private String grade; 


@XmlElement(name="name")
public String getName(){return name;}
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name; 
}

@XmlElement(name="grade")
public String getGrade(){return grade;}
public void setGrade(String grade){
    this.grade = grade;
}
```

Finally, the `StudentList` class:

```
@XmlRootElement (namespace = "myname")
public class StudentList {

//generate wrapper element around students
@XmlElementWrapper(name="student-list")
//set the name of the entities
@XmlElement(name="student")
private ArrayList<Student> studentArrayL = new ArrayList<Student>();

private Map <String, Student> studentList = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Student>();



//sets the student list 
public void setStudentList(String name, String grade){

    Student student = new Student();

    //if ((name != null && !name.isEmpty()) && (grade !=null && !grade.isEmpty())){
        student.setName(name);
        student.setGrade(grade);
        this.studentList.put(name, student);    

        ArrayList<Student> sal = new ArrayList<Student>(studentList.values());
        studentArrayL = sal;
    //}
}



public ArrayList<Student> getStudentListAll(){return studentArrayL;}

public Map<String, Student> getStudentList(){return studentList;}

public void removeStudent(String key){
    studentList.remove(key); 
}
```

}

I am required to run glassfish 3.1 and the 1.X version of jersey. If there is a way to create an XML response from a hashmap, I would prefer to do that, but through my research, it looks like the best method is the conversion to an arraylist.